# StreamPlot,StreamPoints and the Fisher's equation

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to reproduce a `StreamPlot` from a vector field encoundered while analyzing the Fisher's equation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation), for a variable parameter `c` (the speed of the progressive wave).

I have two-three problems.

1A) I wish to draw the stream lines entering the stable node `P` along the directions of the eigenvectors `hP` and exiting from the unstable point `Q` along the directions of the eigenvectors `hQ`, particularly the orbit from `Q` to `P`. I'm unable to do this and to get a single continuous line from `Q` to `P` no matter how I set `StreamPoints`.

1B) If possible I wish to put arrow heads in the middle of a continuos stream lines and not at the end to get a cleaner look.

2) In the right pane of `Manipulate` I wish to get the numeric evaluation of eigenvectors `hP` and `hQ` along with the symbolic expression. The numeric evaluation depends on `c` and `c` is a variable in `Manipulate`.

Basically I wish to reproduce a plot like this:

[1 http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/674/11f5e5.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/674/11f5e5.png)

This is my code (sorry for the bad code indentation, but copying from a Mathematica apparently do not preserve indentation):

```
Module[{A,J,P={0,0},Q={1,0},hP,hQ},
A=c\[Function]({U,V}\[Function]{V,-c V-U+U^2});
J=c\[Function]Evaluate[{U,V}\[Function]Evaluate[Grad[A[c][U,V],{U,V}]]];
hP=c\[Function]Evaluate@Eigenvectors[J[c]@@P];
hQ=c\[Function]Evaluate@Eigenvectors[J[c]@@Q];
Manipulate[
With[{A=A[c],J=J[c],hP=Normalize/@hP[c],hQ=Normalize/@hQ[c]},
StreamPlot[A[U,V],{U,-.5,1.5},{V,-.5,.5},
PlotRangePadding->0.01,AspectRatio->Automatic,
Axes->True,AxesStyle->Directive[Dashed,LightGray],ImageSize->Large,
StreamScale->Full,StreamStyle->Arrowheads[.02],StreamPoints->Fine,StreamColorFunction->"Rainbow",
Prolog->{
PointSize[.02],Darker[Green],Point[P],Text["P",Offset[{10,10},P]],
Gray,If[c>=2,Line[{P-.25#,P+.25#}&/@hP]],

Darker[Red],Point[Q],Text["Q",Offset[{10,10},Q]],
Gray,Line[{Q-.25#,Q+.25#}&/@hQ]
}]
],

{{c,3},0,10,1/4,Appearance->"Labeled"},

Delimiter,
Row[{"A"," = ",MatrixForm[A["c"]["U","V"]]}],
Row[{"J", " = ", MatrixForm[J["c"]["U","V"]],"  Subscript[J, P] = ",MatrixForm[J["c"]@@P],"  Subscript[J, Q] = ",MatrixForm[J["c"]@@Q]}],
Row[{"Subscript[H, P]\[Transpose]", " = ", MatrixForm[hP["c"]]," = ",MatrixForm[hP[c]]}],
Row[{"Subscript[H, Q]\[Transpose]", " = ", MatrixForm[hQ["c"]]," = ",MatrixForm[hQ[c]]}],

ControlPlacement->Right
]
]
```

But I get this:

[image: 2]

## UPDATE

This is another code where I try to use `NDSolve` to draw the stable/unstable mainfold near P and Q. Works only for the curve between Q and P.

```
Module[{A, J, P = {0, 0}, Q = {1, 0}, hP, hQ},
 A = c \[Function] ({U, V} \[Function] {V, -c V - U + U^2});
 J = c \[Function] 
   Evaluate[{U, V} \[Function] Evaluate[Grad[A[c][U, V], {U, V}]]];
 hP = c \[Function] Evaluate[2*Eigenvectors[J[c] @@ P]];
 hQ = c \[Function] Evaluate[2*Eigenvectors[J[c] @@ Q]];

 Manipulate[
  With[{A = A[c], J = J[c], hP = Normalize /@ N@hP[c], 
    hQ = Normalize /@ N@hQ[c], \[Epsilon] = 0.01, 
    t1 = -20*Max[1, c/3], t2 = 20*Max[1, c/3]},
   Module[{g1, g2},

    g1 = Quiet@
        NDSolveValue[{U''[z] + c U'[z] + U[z] (1 - U[z]) == 0, #}, 
         U, {z, t1, t2}] & /@ {
       (*{U[t2],U'[
       t2]}\[Equal]P+\[Epsilon] hP\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\
\[RightDoubleBracket],
       {U[t2],U'[
       t2]}\[Equal]P-\[Epsilon] hP\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\
\[RightDoubleBracket],
       {U[t2],U'[
       t2]}\[Equal]P+\[Epsilon] hP\[LeftDoubleBracket]2\
\[RightDoubleBracket],
       {U[t2],U'[
       t2]}\[Equal]Q+\[Epsilon] hQ\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\
\[RightDoubleBracket],
       {U[t2],U'[
       t2]}\[Equal]Q-\[Epsilon] hQ\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\
\[RightDoubleBracket],
       {U[t1],U'[
       t1]}\[Equal]Q+\[Epsilon] hQ\[LeftDoubleBracket]2\
\[RightDoubleBracket],*)
       {U[t1], U'[t1]} == Q - \[Epsilon] hQ[[2]]
       };

    g1 = Quiet@
      ParametricPlot[
       Evaluate[{#[t], Derivative[1][#][t]} & /@ g1], {t, t1, t2},
       PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.5}, {-.5, .5}},
       Epilog -> {
         PointSize[.02], Darker[Green], Point[P], 
         Text["P", Offset[{10, 10}, P]],
         Gray, If[c >= 2, Line[{P - .1 #, P + .1 #} & /@ hP]],

         Darker[Red], Point[Q], Text["Q", Offset[{10, 10}, Q]],
         Gray, Line[{Q - .1 #, Q + .1 #} & /@ hQ]
         }];

    g2 = StreamPlot[A[U, V], {U, -.5, 1.5}, {V, -.5, .5},
      StreamScale -> Full, StreamStyle -> Arrowheads[.02], 
      StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
      ];

    Show[g1, g2, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.5}, {-.5, .5}}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0.01,
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large,
     Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Directive[Dashed, LightGray]]
    ]
   ],

  {{c, 3}, 0, 10, 1/4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

  Delimiter,
  Column[{
    Row[{"A", " = ", MatrixForm[A["c"]["U", "V"]]}],
    Row[{"J", " = ", MatrixForm[J["c"]["U", "V"]], 
      "  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(P\)]\) = ", 
      MatrixForm[J["c"] @@ P], 
      "  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(Q\)]\) = ", 
      MatrixForm[J["c"] @@ Q]}],
    Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(P\)]\)\[Transpose]", " = ", 
      MatrixForm[hP["c"]]}],
    Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(Q\)]\)\[Transpose]", " = ", 
      MatrixForm[hQ["c"]]}],
    }, Center, 1.5],

  ControlPlacement -> Right
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: To get a plot like the one you indicate, you'll probably have to use `NDSolve`.  I don't think `StreamPlot` will let the stream lines approach each other so closely.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I had some suspect and I did something in this regard. But the biggest issue is A1, and I'm not able to give a useful hint to `StreamPlot` or initial guess to `NDSolve` to draw all the liens for the stable/unstable mainfold...